# SQS: Publish a message when an EC2 instance starts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to automatically publish a message on SQS when an EC2 instance starts?

For example, could you use Cloudwatch to set an [alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) that fires whenever an instance starts up? All the alarms on Cloudwatch appear to be related to a specific EC2 instance, rather than the EC2 service in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand this question and offer a more accurate answer, further information is needed.

Are we talking about:

New instance created and started from *any* AMI ?
New instance created and started from a *specific* AMI?
Starting an *existing* AMI that is just in the stopped state?

Or creating a new instance inside a scale group?

These all affect the way you would **create** your cloudwatch alarm.
For example if it were an existing ec2 you would use status checks as per:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Though if it were a brand new Ec2 instance *created* you would need to use more advanced cloudtrail log alarms as per:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cw_create_alarms.html

However after that point it would follow the same basic logic and that is:

**Create an Alarm that triggers a SNS as per:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsoleAlarms.html

**have that SNS Notifier publish to a SQS topic as per:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

As always though there are many ways to skin a cat.
If it were a critical event and I want the same typical response from every start event I personally would consider bootstrap scripts pushed out from puppet or chef, this way a fast change for all events is centralised in a single script.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Create a Cloud watch Rule to notifiy the creation . As per the lifecycle of EC2 Instance when lauch button is pressed  . Instance goes from Pending state to Running state and If instance is moved from stop state to running state. So create the Rule for Pending state

[Create a Cloud watch Rule as specified in the image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WrU2.png)

Step2 : Create a Step function . Because cloud Trail logs all the event in the account with a delay of atleast 20 min . This step function is usefull if you want the name of user who has created the instance .

```
{
  "StartAt": "Wait",
  "States": {
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 1800,
      "Next": "Ec2-Alert"
    },
   "Ec2-Alert":{
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:321039853697:function:EC2-Creation-Alert",
     "End": true  

  }
  }
}
```

Step3 : Create a SNS topic for notification

Step4 : Write a lambda function to fetch the log from cloud trail and get the user name who has created the instance .

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')
    client1 = boto3.client('sns')
    Instance=event["detail"]["instance-id"]     
    response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
            'AttributeValue': Instance
        },
    ],
    MaxResults=1)

    test=response['Events']

    st="".join(str(x) for x in test)
    print(st)
    user=st.split("Username")[1]
    finalname=user.split(",")
    Creator=finalname[0]
    #print(st[st.find("Username")])

    Email= "Hi All ,\n\n\n The User%s has created new EC2-Instance in QA account and the Instance id is %s \n\n\n Thank you \n\n\n Regard's lamda"%(Creator,Instance)



    response = client1.publish(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:321039853697:Ec2-Creation-Alert',
    Message=Email

)

    # TODO implement
    return {

        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

Note: This code trigger an notification if the instance is changed from stop state to running state or a new instance is launched .